# server.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: apache-kafka

This error is being shown on my command line when I am trying to run this command "kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties" to install Kafka. Can I get any ideas related to it?

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\server.properties (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>               at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:444)enter
>   code here
>               at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:41)
>               at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:57)
>               at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

Comment: It would be helpful, if you would ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure the following path is pointing to the correct destination:

```
.\config\server.properties
```

It ***may*** be two levels up with the following:

```
..\..\config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tut for installation on OS X
https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/installing-kafka-on-mac-osx/
and this tut for installation on Centos 7
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-centos-7
Both of them works in my case. Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The file .\config\server.properties is not found. I think you have the path wrong (or you are not in the right directory)

Answer (score 0):

while you are getting the below exception
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\server.properties (The system cannot find the path specified) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:444)enter code here at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:41) at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:57) at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala).

try to use the following patten it works for sure.

kafka-server-start.bat **strong text** ....\config\server.properties

Answer (score 0):

It depends from where you are executing "kafka-server-start.bat"

1. if you already set PATH in environment variables, then  -> kafka-server-start.bat    ....\config\server.properties
2. else use this -> C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat    ....\config\server.properties